# Debug native code in android using Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I've used maven to integrate JNI code, but I am not able to debug same. Can someone please help me understand how best to place breakpoints in such scenarios.
sample from gradle file:

```
implementation group: "<package>", name: "<lib_name>", version: <lib_version>, changing: true
```

This library is also owned by me so i have access to source code. I am using clang compiler for compiling library

Comment: Please update your question with your gradle file and what details you can provide on the JNI code. Note that if the JNI code is external and not under your control, you may only be able to get a release version.

Comment: updated.Please let me know if other information is required